# How can I include keyevents while macrobenchmarking?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, baseline-profile

I would like to improve the performance of my app by the use of macrobenchmarks. Since my app is based on TV devices, user jounrneys will largely include using keyevents on a remote control.

What I would like to know is how can I emulate keypresses (both tap and hold types) while writing a test inside profileblock? Something like press Dpad DOWN, hold Dpad UP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UiAutomator's `pressDPad*()` methods or `pressKeyCode()`. Check [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice#pressDPadCenter()) for options.

In `profileBlock` you can access `UiDevice` with the `device` property.

Check [JetStream TV sample](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/blob/main/JetStreamCompose/benchmark/src/main/java/com/google/jetstream/benchmark/BaselineProfileGenerator.kt) for inspiration